# MYSQL date_format '%x-%u' equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm having a trouble regarding on my query. I have a code that is originally from MYSQL but I migrated it to Sql Server. Now I don't know if there is a direct equivalent of %x-%u in SQL SERVER.

```
select date_format(date,'%x-%u') AS DATE from date_info WHERE Status = 1;
```

The query should return `YEAR-WEEKNUMBER` where YEAR is the year from the database and WEEK NUMBER is the week number depending on the values and Monday is the 1st day of the week.

sample value for `date` in the database is `2008-01-05 09:48:03`.

And I want to have a result of `2008-1`.

I tried the `DATEPART` function and `FORMAT` function in SQL Server but still I can't find the solution that I wanted. I found using `DATEPART(ISOWK,date)` but it only returns the week number only.

I want the `2008-1` result.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `DATEPART()` and `isowk` format which should return the week of the year.

```
SELECT cast(datepart(yyyy,[date]) as char(4)) + '-' + cast(datepart(isowk,[date]) as char(2)) AS DATE  as date
FROM date_info
WHERE Status = 1
```

As menitoned in the comments by @ZoharPeled this query needed a cast to char , this is the working query.

Comment: Tried executing this but it returns only 2008. Not 2008-1. But the query has no error. :) How come this can happen?

Comment: try adding cast as char(4) to the year and cast as char(2) to the week:`SELECT CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, [date]) as char(4)) +'-'+ CAST(DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, [date]) as char(2))`

Comment: So near yet so far :-) Try SELECT cast(datepart(yyyy,date) as nchar(4)) + '-' + cast(datepart(isowk,date) as nchar(2)) AS DATE
from date_info WHERE Status = 1; - it's parsing the values as numbers, not strings.

Comment: Now it returns 2009. IDK why it adds 1. It supposed to be 2008 but it returns 2009. BTW iam using Microsoft SQL Server Mgmt Studio. Does the code should concatenate the 2 datepart results? If that so, it think it does not concatenate. :)

Comment: @eftpotrm Your code works. I'm curious how this 'cast' works? Can you give a brief explanation?

Comment: @WhiteMark 'cast' is the type conversion function - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx. I've used it here to force the datepart values to be interpreted as strings. Datepart otherwise returns integers, hence the earlier query was trying to make sense of it as an arithmetic operation and returning the result you saw.

Comment: Hah, missed that casting. Shouldn't it cast it self a number to string while trying to concatenate?

Comment: Please note that there is a difference between `ISOWK` and `wk` - the first will start counting the week numbers from the first Monday in the year, while the second will start counting them from the January 1st.

Comment: @eftpotrm  no need for nchar when you can use char.

Comment: @sagi CAST is unhelpful in this regard - it tends to if in doubt try to make everything numbers rather than strings, which tends to trip me up too :-) I'm sure there's a good and useful reason why it's this way round but it's escaping me at present.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I know, fixed before you commented :)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Depends on the application; I'll almost always use nchar/nvarchar as my default to avoid issues with non-ASCII characters. Not an issue here if this isn't concatenated into anything else (in which case I agree char/varchar is fine), but I prefer not having to upgrade retroactively when someone later asks for unicode support.

Comment: @ZoharPeled In oracle, when concanating `||` , integers are automatically converted into strings, doesn't SQL-server does the same?

Comment: @Sagi Sql server does not implicitly cast numbers to strings, in fact it's the other way around - it implicitly  converts strings to numbers on concatenation when the strings are numeric. try this: `SELECT 4 +'-3'+ 4`. the result is `5`. When you do this: `SELECT 4 +'-'+ 4` the result is `8`, since the `'-'` is implicitly converted to `-0`. I was surprised to learn this when writing an answer to this question (that you bit me to by a minute), so thanks, I've learned something new today because of you :-).

Comment: Thats makes two of us:) @ZoharPeled